# What is known about $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{I}^n)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

A few months ago, I asked a related question: [Is $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{I})$ isomorphic to $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{I}^2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392898/is-operatornameaut-mathbbi-isomorphic-to-operatornameaut-mathbbi) It was interesting for me to know that $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{I})\,$ has a normal subgroup of index $2$. Now what other things are known about $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{I}^n)$?
 I guess they are all non-isomorphic . Is there an easy way to show this like the answer in the question which I put a link for?

Another thing: I never studied geometric topology before. Are the above questions closer to geometric topology than algebraic topology?

The reason why I made this guess is because I saw [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_class_group).

I am also trying to get an idea of what Geometric topology is about.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say $Aut(I^n)$, do you mean $Homeo(D^n)$?

Comment: @grumpyparsnip  Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I believe the subgroup of orientation-preserving self-homeomorphisms of $\mathbb{I}^n$ forms a normal subgroup of index 2.

Comment: @MartianInvader beat me to it!

Comment: Conjecture: $\mathbb Z_2^n$ is a subgroup of $Homeo(D^n)$ but not a subgroup of $Homeo(D^{n-1})$. This would distinguish all these groups, but it seems difficult to prove.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Hmmm. I was thinking about another one: $Homeo(D^n)$ has an element of order $2^n$, but does not have an element of order $2^{n+1}$

Comment: @MartianInvader What is the definition of orientation ?

Comment: A definition of orientation which works in the topological (as opposed to the smooth) setting is a consistent choice of generator of $H_n(D^n,D^n\setminus\{p\})$ for all $p\in int(D^n)$.

Comment: @Amr: $Homeo(D^k)$ has elements of any order for $k\geq 2$. They are given by rotations around an axis.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip  OK for the rotations. Where can I read more about orientations ? Are they still inside algebraic topology ?

Comment: @Amr: yes, they are a part of algebraic topology. The best source I know of is the book by Greenberg and Harper.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Your conjecture is interesting. I checked your profile and knew that you are probably a topologist. I will start self-studying AT. I was planning to use Hatcher's AT. Would using the book you mentioned still be a good alternative ? Thank you.

Comment: @amr: Hatcher's book is quite good at giving intuition but seem people find that it has a lack of details. Greenberg and Harper is at the other extreme: very detailed, but significantly less intuition.

Comment: (+1) @Amr: I'm glad you're looking to generalize on the result I posted! That curiosity is mightily fulfilling to see! If I can come up with a way to generalize my result in such a way that it can be shown that the $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb I^n)$ are pairwise non-isomorphic, I will definitely post it.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks. I'm glad to see that you are interested in the question> This question has not drawn much attention, even after I put a bounty on it.

Comment: Sorry for being ignorant, but what exactly is $\mathbb I^n$? I can't find anything useful on google.

Answer (score -1):

You can generalise the result that $Aut(I)$ has an order 2 subgroup.

**Lemma 1** Let $Q_d$ be the edge-graph of a $d$-dimensional hypercube. The automorphism group of $Q_d$ is isomorphic to a wreath product $\Sigma_2\wr\Sigma_d$, also called the [hyperoctohedral group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoctahedral_group) in dimension $d$. Here $\Sigma_i$ is the symmetric group on $i$ elements.

**Corollary 2** $$|Aut(Q_d)|=2^dd!$$

**Theorem 3** The automorphism group $Aut(I^d)$ has a subgroup of order $2^dd!$.

The above is a consequence of corollary 2 and $Aut(Q_d)$ being realised as a subgroup of $Aut(I^d)$. A proof of the above lemma can be found [here](http://www.jucs.org/jucs_6_1/the_automorphism_group_of/Harary_F.pdf)<sup>[1]</sup>.

[1] Frank Harary. *The Automorphism Group of a Hypercube.* J. UCS **6**(1): 136-138 (2000).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Note: I was saying that $Aut(\mathbb{I})$ has a normal subgroup of index $2$ and not that $Aut(\mathbb{I})$ has a subgroup of order $2$ (Of course the second statement is true as well, but it is easier to show than the first)

Comment: @Amr Ah, well if you take the canonical homomorphism $\varphi \colon Aut(I^d)\rightarrow Aut(Q_d)$ sending an automorphism to its effect on vertices, then $\ker\varphi$ is a normal subgroup of $Aut(I^d)$ of index $2^dd!$. The group $\ker\varphi$ can be identified with the subgroup of automorphisms of $I^d$ which fix the vertices of $Q_d$.

Comment: In fact, the above homomorphism gives a right split exact sequence $$0\rightarrow \ker \varphi \rightarrow Aut(I^d) \stackrel{\leftarrow}{\rightarrow} Aut(Q_d) \rightarrow 0$$ and so we get a semidirect product $Aut(I^d) \cong \ker \varphi \rtimes Aut(Q_d)$.

Comment: Dear @DanielRust, I am a bit confused . Let's consider the case $d=2$. Is $Q_2$ the set $\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)\}$ ? or it is the boundary of $\mathbb{I}\times\mathbb{I}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$? I also assume that by $Aut(Q_d)$ you mean the group of homeomorphisms of $Aut(Q_d)$ .

Comment: If $Q_d$ is the set of the 4 vertices of the square,then I don't see why this set will be fixed by every homeomorphism $h\in Aut(\mathbb{I}\times\mathbb{I})$ (In the sense that $h[Q_d]=Q_d$). If $Q_d$ is the boundary of the square, then I fail to see how can $Aut(Q_d)$ be finite .

Comment: Reading you first comment again. You say that : "Ker$\phi$ can just be identified with the subgroup of automorphisms that fix the vertices of $Q_d$". Going back to the case $d=2$, I interpret what you said as "the subgroup of $Aut(\mathbb{I}\times\mathbb{I})$ that fix the 4 vertices of the square $\mathbb{I}\times \mathbb{I}$." It is true that this is a subgroup of $Aut(\mathbb{I}\times\mathbb{I})$, but I don't think at all that it has to be normal.

Comment: @Amr Sorry, I'm only now realising that I've been implicitly considering $I^d$ as a CW-complex and $Aut(I^d)$ as the group of skeleton-preserving homeomorphisms on $I^d$. Considering $I^d$ instead as just a topological space, the above map is not well defined (and so not a homomorphism). $Aut(Q_d)$ is still a subgroup but there is now no surjective homomorphism on to the group (as far as I know) as there exist homomorphisms on $I^d$ which do not preserve the $0$-skeleton. ($Q_d$ is the graph of edges and vertices of the $d$-cube).

Comment: There *is* a surjective homomorphism on to the automorphism group of the $d$-sphere, $Aut(S^d)$, with kernel the group of homeomorphisms of $I^d$ which fix the boundary.

Comment: Yes. I already guessed before that every homeomorphism of $I^d$ must fix its boundary in $R^d$, in the sense that $h(\partial I^d)=\partial I^d$ (This can be used later to show that $Aut(S^{d-1})$ is the homomorphic image of $Aut(I^d)$). I'd like to know a proof for this fact as well.